# SQL Hibernate is not retuning the same results as a direct SQL query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a **Java** app which interfaces with **MySQL** via **Hibernate**.

In my code, I have the app executing the SQL command:

```
final SQLQuery query = sf.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
            "select\n" +
            "   id, null as store_id, case when transaction_type = 'SALE' then 1 else -1 end as sign, payment_type,\n" +
            "   sum(cost_before_tax) as amount_before_tax, sum(tax_amount) as tax_amount, sum(cost) as amount,\n" +
            "   sum(ticket_count) as count\n" +
            "from settlement_collection_initial_settlement\n" +
            "where\n" +
            "   business_date between :start and :end\n" +
            (storeID != null ? "    and store_id = :store\n" : "") +
            "group by transaction_type, payment_type"
        );
        query.addEntity(AmountRow.class);
        query.setDate("start", start);
        query.setDate("end", end != null ? end : start);
        if (storeID != null) {
            query.setString("store", new UUIDType().toSQLString(storeID));
        }
        return query.list();
```

And `query.list()` returns:
[image]

However, if I run the **exact same** query in *MySqlWorkbench*:

```
select
    id, store_id, case when transaction_type = 'SALE' then 1 else -1 end as sign, payment_type,
    sum(cost_before_tax) as amount_before_tax, sum(tax_amount) as tax_amount, sum(cost) as amount,
    sum(ticket_count) as count
from settlement_collection_initial_settlement
where
    business_date between '2018-07-27' and '2018-07-27'
    and store_id = 'xxxxxx'
group by transaction_type, payment_type
```

I get the results:
[image]

Notice that those results are *close*, but **not the same**. Have a look at the two `CASH` lines, and the direct SQL shows a second `CASH` line with a different `sign` and other values. So in essense, the Hibernate executed sql is repeating that *CASH* line.

To me, it looks like both ways should return the exact same results.
**Does anyone see why my Hibernate SQL is returning different (wrong) results from when I directly execute the SQL?**

**UPDATE**:

Here is my `AmountRow` class:

```
@Entity
public class AmountRow {

    static final int SIGN_SALE_OR_DEBIT = 1, SIGN_REFUND_OR_CREDIT = -1;

    @Id
    private float id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "store_id", nullable = true)
    private Store store;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Payment.Type paymentType;

    private int sign;

    // NOTE: "$" is the name of a custom class
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "com.mycompany.service.$Type")
    private $ amountBeforeTax, taxAmount, amount;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int count;

    // Hibernate constructor
    protected AmountRow() {}

    // NOTE: "$" is the name of a custom class
    AmountRow(final $ amountBeforeTax, final $ taxAmount, final $ amount, final int count, final int sign) {
        Assert.noneNull(amountBeforeTax, "amountBeforeTax", taxAmount, "taxAmount", amount, "amount");
        Assert.notNegative(count, "count");
        assertValidSign(sign);
        this.amountBeforeTax = amountBeforeTax;
        this.taxAmount = taxAmount;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.count = count;
        this.sign = sign;
    }

    // NOTE: "$" is the name of a custom class
    AmountRow(final $ amountBeforeTax, final $ taxAmount, final $ amount, final int count, final int sign, final Payment.Type paymentType) {
        this(amountBeforeTax, taxAmount, amount, count, sign);
        this.paymentType = paymentType;
    }

    static void assertValidSign(final int sign) {
        if (sign != SIGN_SALE_OR_DEBIT && sign != SIGN_REFUND_OR_CREDIT)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid sign " + sign);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "AmountRow[paymentType=" + paymentType + ", sign=" + sign + ", amountBeforeTax=" + amountBeforeTax + ", taxAmount=" + taxAmount + ", amount=" + amount + ", count=" + count + "]";
    }

    public Store getStore() {
        return store;
    }

    public Payment.Type getPaymentType() {
        return paymentType;
    }

    public int getSign() {
        return sign;
    }

    public $ getAmountBeforeTax() {
        return amountBeforeTax;
    }

    public $ getTaxAmount() {
        return taxAmount;
    }

    public $ getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public $ getAmountBeforeTaxPerCount() {
        return count != 0 ? amountBeforeTax.divide(count) : null;
    }

    public $ getAmountPerCount() {
        return count != 0 ? amount.divide(count) : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing such thing: `null as store_id`?

Comment: Time interval truncation or time zone differences between JVM and the database? You're not showing the exact date values passed into the Hibernate query.

Comment: @Mnemonic I don't think so. But how could I find this out?

Comment: How is the Date object created? Since it's using the old Date API, the only valid way is to use `cal = Calendar.getInstance()`, then `cal.clear(); cal.set(year,month,date);`, then `query.setDate("start", cal.getTime());` It's a horrible API, but @MickMnemonic is probably right that it's the source of the problem.

Comment: Use spy4j and see generates SQL

Comment: There are missing pieces of info: MySQL type of business_date, is `id` and autoincrement column?, why not `group by sign`?, Hibernate version. Additionally, setDate() is deprecated.

Comment: Could you post your `AmountRow` class? What is `id` column definition?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I have added the `AmountRow` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by different timezone between your application and your DB.

Either:

- Use absolute time like Epoch millisecond to represent time (Work regardless timezone) OR
- Check timezone of your application and sql server, choose and convert your Date to a common timezone

Your HSQL also expose another problem in your code: There's a duplicated result.

Your should post your `AmountRow` class for further investigation.

**Update**

After reading your `AmountRow` class, the problem is usage of float as `@Id` key would cause wrong equality check, makes Hibernate not load the data from DB. You should never rely on float/double equality.

@df778899 has an excellent explanation for this issue.

Change the `@Id` field to long/int to solve the duplication.

Comment: why you mark `id` as float? Make it int/long I think

Comment: This was it for sure. Wow. I certainly learned something here. Thanks to Manh and df778899 for helping me understand this.

Answer (score 4):

@Manh is right in his earlier comment about the `id` as a float.  He deserves the answer + bounty - just using an answer to allow room to explain...

The reason is that Hibernate manages objects in its session in a `StatefulPersistenceContext`.  Entities in there are effectively keyed in a `HashMap` by the `@Id` value.  (The real key class is an `org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey`, but the `equals()` method on here will, still indirectly, drill down to `Float.equals()` against the two auto-boxed `float id` values).

Those `id` values have too much precision for a float - the limit is typically about 7 digits:

```
16842421f -> (float) 1.684242E7
16842423f -> (float) 1.6842424E7
16842419f -> (float) 1.684242E7
```

Clearly rows 0 and 2 will be treated as having equal `id` values, and therefore seen as the same entity instance by Hibernate.  As @Manh says, an `int` or a `long` would cope better.

Comment: Thanks for your kind word. Your explanation is correct. 
Use float in this case cause wrong equality check for `@Id` field and make the third rows duplicated. +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

try to use HQL

```
select
id, store_id, case when transaction_type = 'SALE' then 1 else -1 end as sign, payment_type,
sum(cost_before_tax) as amount_before_tax, sum(tax_amount) as tax_amount, sum(cost) as amount,
sum(ticket_count) as count
from settlement_collection_initial_settlement
where
    business_date between :beginDate and :endDate
    and store_id = :storeID
group by transaction_type, payment_type
```

create a string from the query and then:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("beginDate ", start);
query.setParameter("endDate", end != null ? end : start);
query.setParameter("storeID", storeID);
return query.list();
```

also another good advice is to always check your connection string, that you are connecting to the same database

Comment: To use HQL, there would need to be a corresponding entity that matches `settlement_collection_initial_settlement`. Also, the `case...when` syntax might not work directly like in SQL.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. In fast, it duplicated two other rows instead of the two posted above.

Comment: Also, connection strings are identical in code and workbench.

Comment: and can you try the same code but just as SQL query, 
you will need to change only
createQuery(hql) to createSQLQuery(hql);

Comment: No difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the content of the ArrayList (the one holding Hibernate resultset), you will notice the 1st and 3rd row have the exact same address (`@7427`).
This means the same database row is repeated twice.
This also indicates that **Hibernate is considering that the 3rd read record is identical to the 1st one** (which is already present in current Session).
So IMHO, you have to investigate why these 2 AmountRow instances are evaluated as equals (> check equalsTo(), compareTo() and hashCode() implementation).
NB: To validate my diagnostic, you can return a Set (and not List) and check its size. I expect a size of 2...

Comment: You are correct here. I suppose the real question is: why is the Hibernate code returning "2" unique results, when the direct SQL query (via MySQLWorkbench) is returning 3 unique results?

Comment: As pointed out, it might be because of a wrong implementation of equalsTo(), compareTo() and hashCode() methods in "AmountRow" class (or in one of its super classes)

Comment: My `AmountRow` class does not `equalsTo()`, `compareTo()` and `hashCode()` methods. Would I need to add those maybe?

Comment: That would be interesting to implement these 3 methods and put a breakpoint on each of them in order to better understand what is happenning